# Sparql Query to get all the possible movies available from dbpedia

Tags: wikipedia, sparql, dbpedia

To get all the possible film name, I used sparql query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?film_title ?film_abstract
WHERE {
?film_title rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
?film_title rdfs:comment ?film_abstract 
}
```

It returned me only 10,000 movies. 
DBpedia mentions on its website that it has around 60,000 movies.
For my application I need all the possible movies. Could someone guide me what all other possibilities are there to get rest of the movies

Comment: why don't you accept any answers to your questions? This behaviour discourages people to help you...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

DBPedia has a cap on how many results it can return in one call. If you want to get all of them you can do it through multiple queries using limit and offset e.g. (limit 1000 offset 0, limit 1000 offset 1000 etc.). So you first query would be:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?film_title ?film_abstract
WHERE {
?film_title rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
?film_title rdfs:comment ?film_abstract 
} LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```